# Sort a structure in descending order

Tags: c, struct

I have to sort this strucure in descending order, based on the "med" variable stored in this strucure, so if students 1 med > students 2 med, then the struct shall be printed as : * student 2 info * then * student 1 info *

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
struct om
{
    char name[20];
    int n1,n2,n3;
    float med;
} a[3];

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Student's data");
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName:");
        scanf("%s", a[i].name);
        printf("\nGrade at maths:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].n1);
        printf("\nGrade at programming:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].n2);
        printf("\nGrade at english:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].n3);
        a[i].med=(a[i].n1+a[i].n2+a[i].n3)/3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `man qsort`. You will need a custom sorting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this, try to understand how the sorting function works based on some example inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_STUDENTS 3

struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int math, prog, engl;
    double avg;

} students[NUM_STUDENTS];

static int compare_students(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  double avg1 = ((struct student *)s1)->avg;
  double avg2 = ((struct student *)s2)->avg;

  return (avg1 > avg2) - (avg1 < avg2);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Student data:\n");

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s", students[i].name);

        printf("Grade at maths:");
        scanf("%d", &students[i].math);

        printf("Grade at programming:");
        scanf("%d", &students[i].prog);

        printf("Grade at english:");
        scanf("%d", &students[i].engl);

        students[i].avg = (double)students[i].math + students[i].prog + students[i].engl) / NUM_STUDENTS;
    }

    qsort(students, NUM_STUDENTS, sizeof(struct student), compare_students);

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %d: %s\n", i, students[i].name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to make some general improvements, like adding a `#define` for the number of students, using more readable variable names and using `double` instead of `float` variables (using the latter almost never makes sense in practice). Also note that your average calculation was wrong before because the result was truncated.

Answer (score 0):

```
man_d_sort(struct om a[])
{
   if (a[0].med >= a[1].med)
   {
        if (a[0].med >= a[2].med)
            printf("%.2lf", a[0].med);
        else
            printf("%.2lf", a[2].med);
   } 
   else
   {
        if (a[1].med >= a[2].med)
            printf("%.2lf ", a[1].med);
        else
            printf("%.2lf ", a[2].med);
   }
}
```

Comment: function to find the higest marks. I hope it'll help you